# What EXACTLY is the "basic operation" in this given algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, complexity-theory, analysis

So I have this algorithm and I am trying to determine the basic operation for an algorithm analysis problem.

here is the code:

```
median(int array[]){
int k = array.length();
int n = k/2;
    for(int i = 0; i < k; i++){
    int numsmaller = 0;
    int numequal = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < k; k++){
        if(array[j] < array[i]){
        numsmaller++;
        }else
        if(array[j] == array[i]){
        numequal++;
        }
if(numsmaller < n && n <= (numsmaller + numequal){
return array[i]
}
                                   }//inner loop
                                 }//outter loop
}//end of function
```

I am under the current impression that the basic operation of this Algorithm is the two if statements within the inner loop of the function.
What is confusing me is that, I am unsure if the basic operation is the boolean expression itself which would be executed every iteration checking if array[j] < array[i] and if array[j] is equal to array[i]. Or weather the basic operation is the code execution that occurs when either of the if statements are true. Can someone please give me a solid explanation in terms of algorithm analysis what the basic operation of this algorithm would be :) please and much thanks

Comment: i think it is, when either of the statement is true

Answer (score 1):

Basic operations may be things like:

- Array indexing
- Conditionals, i.e. `if (x == y)`
- Assignments, i.e. `x = 10`
- And even basic math operations, i.e. `y + 2`

Note this is not an exhaustive list by any means. Also note that the worst case scenario of some code requires the maximum number of basic operations to be performed; so in the following code, you'll see *three* basic operations in the worst case.

```
if (variable == true) {
  int x = y + 2;
}
```

...this is because we really just composed several of the above list items. We have to perform the first conditional no matter one (one basic op) but after that the "worst case scenario" is when `variable = true`, because we then continue to perform an assignment. Of course in order to compute the non-obvious value that `x` will assume via the assignment, we have to perform another basic operation (arithmetic between `y` and 2) which gives us a total of three basic operations.

So in your case, the basic operations performed in the inner loop are the conditionals, the incrementing (basically assignment) of a variable given one of the conditions are met, and the two conditionals plus arithmetic done in the

```
if(numsmaller < n && n <= (numsmaller + numequal)
```

line.

Hopefully this helps.